# Where are the Ruin Crystals (PDA batteries) in Blast Brigade vs. the Evil Legion of Dr. Cread

Tags: blast-brigade

I am at 60% exploration and only found 1 ruin crystal.
Where are all the ruin crystals to exchange for PDA batteries?